# elasticbeanstalk multicontainer will not pick the latest Image from

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecr

I have a python server setup of multi containers with Dockerrun.aws.json file that picks up the images from ECR:

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
"volumes": [
    {
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "API"
        },
        "name": "_Api"
    }
],
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "essential": true,
        "Update": true,
        "memory": 128,
        "name": "my_api",
        "image": "xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-api:test1",
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "containerPath": "/code",
                "sourceVolume": "_Api"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 128,
        "name": "nginx",
        "image": "xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dashboard-nginx:test1",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 80,
                "hostPort": 80
            }
        ],
         "links": [
             "my_api"
         ]
    },
    {
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 128,
        "name": "redis",
        "image": "redis:latest",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 6379,
                "hostPort": 6379
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have done some modifications to the containers and wish to test it locally using the `eb local run` command
But no matter what i do it is using original old images

I have a parallel docker-compose.yml i was using before EB - which works as expected:

```
       version: '3'
services:
   my_api:
       image: xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-api:test1
       build: ./API
       expose:
           - "5555"
       volumes:
           - ./API:/code
       depends_on:
           - redis
   redis:
       image: redis:latest
       networks:
         - service
       ports:
           - "6379:6379"
       expose:
           - "6379"
   nginx:
       image: xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-nginx:test1
       build:
           context: ./API
           dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
       ports:
           - 80:80
       depends_on:
           - my_api
```

I tried to build and push with docker-compose . and with docker , with a new tag and more 
But still i get the same behavior

The .elasticbeanstalk/docker-compose.yml file seems to get updated , but even running docker-compose up --build with it still uses the older image

I tried running docker system prune -a to make eb pull the new tagged container - but still , somehow, i got the old images again

Even deploy to AWS acts the same

When i run the docker ps -a , i can see that the containers used are only different by their names but uses different image ids:

```
89b258852e84        xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-nginx:test1   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   9 minutes ago       Exited (0) 5 minutes ago                       dashboard-nginx
23196d6e8016        xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-api:test1     "uwsgi --ini app.ini"    9 minutes ago       Exited (0) 5 minutes ago                       dashboard-api
95b4473bc38f        redis:latest                                                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 minutes ago       Exited (0) 5 minutes ago                       live_dashboard_redis_1
32be5539e905        xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-nginx:test1   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   10 minutes ago      Exited (0) 6 minutes ago                       elasticbeanstalk_nginx_1
51d89fcdfd94        redis:latest                                                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 minutes ago      Exited (0) 6 minutes ago                       elasticbeanstalk_redis_1
e10715455525        xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-api:test1     "uwsgi --ini app.ini"    10 minutes ago      Exited (0) 6 minutes ago                       elasticbeanstalk_myapi_1
```

What have i missed or did not fully understand ?
is there any way to make eb local rebuild and use the latest images locally?
Why is not EB pull the latest version of an Image when deploying ?
Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated

EDIT1

Some more info i gathered
when i inspect the docker-compose image and the eb one i can see they have a diffrent Mount section which can explain the code diffrences :

docker-compose

```
"Mounts": [
   {
       "Type": "bind",
       "Source": "/host_mnt/c/Workspaces/PRJ/DevOps/Tools/proj/API",

       "Destination": "/code",

       "Mode": "rw",
       "RW": true,
       "Propagation": "rprivate"
   }
]
```

eb:

```
       "Mounts": [
           {
               "Type": "volume",
               "Name": "API",
               "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/API/_data",
               "Destination": "/code",
               "Driver": "local",
               "Mode": "rw",
               "RW": true,
               "Propagation": ""
           }
       ]
```

strange as i am working on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days with AWS Support on the phone
Finally we got an answer
So if anyone face this in the future , you need to check your mount setup

Make the volume pick from   /var/app/current/API

```
"volumes": [
    {
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/API"
        },
        "name": "_Api"
    }
],
```